# Outlook 2007/10 email html formatting issue with table elements

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm having problems removing a 1px border (at least, that's what it appears to be) between some of the table elements in this page:
http://tkevents.ca/microsoft/cls2012/email_en_new.html

This page renders fine in Chrome, FIrefox, Safari and IE 6 through 9. The problem is in Outlook 2007 & 2010. It looks like some of the td tags have picked up an extra 1 px border or something.

Screenshot: (I can't post an image - my account is too new). But, you can duplicate this by embedding the code in an Outlook message.

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong... I've applied a bunch of suggestions from other answers within Stack Overflow, all with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, add this to your css.

```
table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion George. That didn't work though.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I figured this one out... the border-collapse was part of it - I was using that prior to asking this question, thus, it wasn't helping get me where I needed to be. The problem was with the table width/height: I had to adjust the size of the images so that they forced exact measurements on the table I was building.